# Does YugabyteDB support Django even though the SAVEPOINTS feature is not yet supported?

Tags: django, yugabytedb

Have a Django app setup to talk to YugabyteDB, but while running migrations we run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 54, in get_for_model
    ct = self.get(app_label=opts.app_label, model=opts.model_name)
  File "/opt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
__fake__.DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 464, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/opt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
__fake__.DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/opt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_prometheus/db/common.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(CursorWrapper, self).execute(*args, **kwargs)
psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: SAVEPOINT <transaction> not supported yet
LINE 1: SAVEPOINT "s140500455238528_x1"
        ^
HINT:  See https://github.com/YugaByte/yugabyte-db/issues/1125. Click '+' on the description to raise its priority
```

Since YugabyteDB does not appear to support SAVEPOINTS today, how can we get around this Django error?

[DISCLAIMER: This question was first asked by a YugabyteDB user over email]

Answer (score 3):

YugabyteDB is going to support [Savepoint feature](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/9219) in the newer releases. So this issue may not be seen.

However, we have built a [Django backend for YugabyteDB](https://github.com/yugabyte/yb-django). It ensures the compatibility of YugabyteDB with Django. Until the newer releases make it to the production environments, we have disabled the Savepoint support in the backend i.e. the backend tells Django that it does not support savepoints (uses_savepoints = False) and so Django will not use savepoints automatically and this exception should not be seen. However, the atomicity of the outermost transaction is still guaranteed.

Also, one should not use the savepoint API explicitly, as it going to be a no-op, unless you are on a version of YB that supports savepoint.